# Firebase Cloud Function Increment Counter

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Per Firebase cloud functions [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), "Events are delivered at least once, but a single event may result in multiple function invocations. Avoid depending on exactly-once mechanics, and write idempotent functions."

When looking at a firestore cloud function doc example below of a restaurant rating, they are using an increment counter to calculate the total number of ratings. **What are some of the best ways to maintain the accuracy of this counter by using an idempotent function?**

Is it reasonable to store the context.eventId in a subcollection document field and only execute the function if the new context.eventId is different?

```
function addRating(restaurantRef, rating) {
    // Create a reference for a new rating, for use inside the transaction
    var ratingRef = restaurantRef.collection('ratings').doc();

    // In a transaction, add the new rating and update the aggregate totals
    return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
        return transaction.get(restaurantRef).then((res) => {
            if (!res.exists) {
                throw "Document does not exist!";
            }

            // Compute new number of ratings
            var newNumRatings = res.data().numRatings + 1;

            // Compute new average rating
            var oldRatingTotal = res.data().avgRating * res.data().numRatings;
            var newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + rating) / newNumRatings;

            // Commit to Firestore
            transaction.update(restaurantRef, {
                numRatings: newNumRatings,
                avgRating: newAvgRating
            });
            transaction.set(ratingRef, { rating: rating });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to store the context.eventId in a subcollection
> document field and only execute the function if the new
> context.eventId is different?

Yes, for your use case, using the Cloud Function `eventId` is the best solution to make you Cloud Function idempotent. I guess you have already watched this Firebase [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pwsy8XR7HNE&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM&index=4).

In the [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation) from which you have taken the code in your question, you will find at the bottom, the similar code for a Cloud Function. I've adapted this code as follows, in order to check if a doc with ID = `eventId` exists in a dedicated `ratingUpdateIds` subcollection:

```
exports.aggregateRatings = functions.firestore
    .document('restaurants/{restId}/ratings/{ratingId}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {

        try {

            // Get value of the newly added rating
            const ratingVal = change.after.data().rating;
            const ratingUpdateId = context.eventId;

            // Get a reference to the restaurant
            const restRef = db.collection('restaurants').doc(context.params.restId);

            // Get a reference to the ratingUpdateId doc
            const ratingUpdateIdRef = restRef.collection("ratingUpdateIds").doc(ratingUpdateId);

            // Update aggregations in a transaction
            await db.runTransaction(async (transaction) => {

                const ratingUpdateIdDoc = await transaction.get(ratingUpdateIdRef);

                if (ratingUpdateIdDoc.exists) {
                    // The CF is retried
                    throw "The CF is being retried";
                }

                const restDoc = await transaction.get(restRef);

                // Compute new number of ratings
                const newNumRatings = restDoc.data().numRatings + 1;

                // Compute new average rating
                const oldRatingTotal = restDoc.data().avgRating * restDoc.data().numRatings;
                const newAvgRating = (oldRatingTotal + ratingVal) / newNumRatings;

                // Update restaurant info and set ratingUpdateIdDoc
                transaction
                    .update(restRef, {
                        avgRating: newAvgRating,
                        numRatings: newNumRatings
                    })
                    .set(ratingUpdateIdRef, { ratingUpdateId })

            });

            return null;

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return null;
        }

    });
```

PS: I made the assumption that the Cloud Function `eventId` can be used as a [Firestore document ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). I didn't find any doc or info stating the opposite. In case using the `eventId` as an ID would be a problem, since you execute the transaction in a Cloud Function (and therefore use the Admin SDK), you could query the document based on a field value (where you store the `eventId`) instead of getting it through a Reference based on its ID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was looking for practical ways people write idempotent cloud functions. The solution you presented seems reasonable to me but could potentially require a cleanup function. I may continue to pursue adding the eventId as a field in a rating subcollection document